# Transfer ERC20 Tokens (USDT) from a Hacked Wallet, send gas fees and transfer tokens in 1 transaction

Tags: remix, transactions, hardhat, usdt

My wallet got compromised and I have an ERC20 USDT, so the attack on my wallet is that any ETH that enters my wallet automatically gets transferred out the next second without my notice.

So I can't have Access to any Eth to pay for the gas fee to move out my ERC20 USDT, please does anyone have any idea on how I can move my usdt tokens from that wallet?

Please help a brother

Answer (score 1):

If this is in Ethereum L1 network, you should probably use something like Flashbots to rescue your assets. If you don't have the know-how yourself, you can contact the team in their [Discord](https://docs.flashbots.net/) and they may be able to assist you for a fee.

I don't know if any other network has a similar mechanism - so if your assets are not in Ethereum L1, then I can't really help you further.